# How can I find the saved password in Android browser?

Tags: password, stock-browser

I have Prestigio Tablet with ICS. I forgot a password from important site. It's remembered in the tablet's browser. How can I see it without rooting the tablet?

Comment: And this site doesn't have a password recovery mechanism?

Answer (score 4):

There is no functionality to view saved passwords included in the stock browser.

The only method for retrieving passwords saved in the stock browser is to open the `webview.db` file (it's an sqlite database) in `/data/data/com.android.browser` and look at the password table (it's stored in the clear, no encryption or anything), but that requires root.

Answer (score 1):

The best decision so far is:
Download SQLite Database editor. (Root is required!)

Go to "Application Databases"
Choose : Internet (with icon of Earth and small script com.android.browser /data/data/com.android.browser/databases/webview.db

Choose from TABLES - "password"
Press SELECT*

ENJOY!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can try those 3 steps, using 2 devices (second must be rooted):

1. use `adb backup com.android.browser` to create a backup of browser on your device
2. use TitaniumBackup to restore to another device
3. copy `webview.db` from `/data/data/com.android/browser/databases/` and extract password from it.