# How to retrieve saved password in Google Chrome for Android?

Tags: chrome-for-android, password, privacy, url

Is there any way I can retrieve stored password specific to any URL in Google Chrome for Android. This is not in any way connected with Google Chrome running in Desktop versions. I'm able to see saved password in Google Chrome in Desktop but not in Android version. Please Help. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Related link [How can I find the saved password in Android browser?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/42371/how-can-i-find-the-saved-password-in-android-browser)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In Windows, if you open Manage password in Chrome, then it asks for a master password (i.e. Windows Admin password) to view and manage your passwords. But that's not the case in Android. So for security purposes, Chrome for Android doesn't reveal the password.

> [From Greenbot](http://www.greenbot.com/article/2933422/how-to-manage-your-chrome-saved-passwords-on-android.html): Saving your passwords to your device presents some obvious security
>   issues. Although Chrome won’t show your password, all bets are off If
>   someone gets ahold of your phone—they’ll be able to log into any
>   account that Chrome remembers. If you choose to have Chrome remember
>   your passwords, you’ll also want to set a passcode on your phone—or
>   better yet, encrypt your device—to reduce the risk of your Internet
>   accounts falling onto the wrong hands.

Based on [this help link](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95606?hl=en#Android%20device), to manage you password in Chrome browser for Android,

> 1. Open the Chrome app.
> 2. Touch Chrome menu Menu.
> 3. Touch Settings > Save passwords.
> 4. Touch the link for Manage saved passwords in your Google Account.

However, following the above steps only reveals the username and the website URL and you can delete the password but not view it. In order to manage/view your passwords from any device/browser, visit https://passwords.google.com and re-enter you Google account password to login and to view all your saved passwords (except your currently signed in Google account password won't be displayed) if,

- you’ve signed in to Chrome and saved passwords or
- you’re using Google Smart Lock for Passwords on Android

Click on the specific website and select the eye symbol to reveal the password for that particular site.

**Update:**

If you are having a rooted device, you can try [Firelord's answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/119610/27149) too.

Comment: Or just set up DNS server to redirect request for specific site to the one you control, log in with remembered password on android and retrieve password on the site (requires some coding). And if the target site is served with `https` you'll also have to install root certificate on android and use it to sign the certificate for your password-collecting site.

Comment: You should add that this does not work if one has set a sync passphrase to encrypt Chrome's cloud data.

Answer (score 7):

**Note**: This method requires root access.

---

The credentials of the websites that you allowed Chrome to save are stored in the file `Login data` which is located inside the data directory of Chrome i.e. `/data/data/com.android.chrome/app_chrome/Default/`. Certainly, no app or even ADB can access that location and neither Chrome has any provision through GUI to access them, so non-rooted devices are at quite a loss. [Lucky's solution](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/115790/96277) should help in that case.

Anyhow, for a rooted device, simply pull that file (an SQLite database) into PC and open it  in an SQLite viewer like [DB Browser for SQLite](http://sqlitebrowser.org/). You may also open that file in a text viewer (know that the formatting wouldn't be pleasing if you do that and a bit incomprehensible too) or in an SQLite viewer app like [SQLite Editor](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.speedsoftware.sqleditor) or [aSQLiteManager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=dk.andsen.asqlitemanager) or the command-line [sqlite3](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ptSoft.util.sqlite3forroot).

The table `logins` has the credentials.

Comment: The column `password_value` in that SQLite database doesn't show the password as plain text. It shows `BLOB (size: X)` (`X` is a number like `8`, `13` and so on...). How to retrieve the password?

Comment: Try a different SQLite Browser. I tried Sqliteman and came across this issue. I later tried DB Browser for SQLite which worked.

Comment: Do you know a SQLite viewer that works on Android?

Comment: I opened the database as text and most passwords were visible in plaintext.

Answer (score 4):

Another way to do this (e.g. if you use a sync password and passwords.google.com is not an option) is by turning debug mode on, inspecting the tab, and printing the value of the field at the console (e.g. document.getElementById('passwordFieldID').value;)

Link for remote debugging: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging

Answer (score 2):

[image]

[image]

You'll be prompted to enter your lockscreen password or PIN if you have one, or your Google password if you don't have a lockscreen.