# View chrome passwords on Android device

Tags: chrome-for-android, password

I've been searching for a way to do this for a while now and haven't come up with a good solution. Does anyone know if chrome-saved passwords can be viewed on an android device? If they can't be, is there a particular reason this feature hasn't been built?

Thanks!

Comment: No you can't view saved passwords on Google Chrome Android Browser. But instead you can try this answer on [How to retrieve saved password in Google Chrome for Android?](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/115790/27149). It hasn't been built-in for security reason that any one who has an access to your phone's browser might get to know the password easily since there is no master password protect feature in Chrome Android unlink the desktop version.

Comment: In case, if the device is rooted, see my answer [here](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/115786/96277).